# Very slow migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

My latest migration runs very slowly (600 seconds) even though it is not doing much

I have a model that contains tags in a string format separated with commas like so :

Model.tags = "TAG1, TAG2, TAG3"

I want to create a new Tag model that has a has_and_belongs_to_many relation with my model

Here is the migration

```
def self.up
rename_column :pizzas, :tags, :tags_migration

create_table :tags do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.integer :count
  t.timestamps
end

create_join_table :tags, :pizzas do |t|
  t.index [:tag_id, :pizza_id]
end

Pizza.all.each do |pizza|
  pizza_tags = pizza.tags_migration
  unless pizza_tags.empty?
    pizza_tags_array = pizza_tags.split(', ')
    pizza_tags_array.each do |tag|
      t = Tag.find_by(name: tag)
      if t.nil?
        t = Tag.new
        t.name = tag
        t.count = 1
      else
        t.count = t.count + 1
      end
      t.pizzas << pizza
      t.save
      pizza.tags << t
      pizza.save
    end
  end
  puts "pizza n" + pizza.id.to_s
end
end
```

I don't think this code is supposed to take this long ( i have around 2000 entries )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you may be holding quite a bit in memory (due to `Pizza.all`).  A simple performance benefit would be to change `Pizza.all.each` to `Pizza.find_each`

Answer (score 1):

1. A good point by @codenamev about `find_each`
2. You have n+1 query in Tag.find_by(name: tag)
3. And also here

-

```
t.pizzas << pizza
t.save
pizza.tags << t
pizza.save
```

You can run the whole thing in a transaction to commit all the changes at once (but it may cause locks)

I'm not sure about the implementation details but the code above could be cut in half as `t.pizzas << pizza` will assign both models. `has_many ... :through` association should handle this

Also, consider moving the update part outside of migration as it will lock the database for a while